# If I have HTML before the php script, would it increase page load performance?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

Now for my page, on some slow mobile devices, it takes a rather long time to load. I had all the database retrieval on the top of the page. I wonder if I put the database thing on the end of the page, like the way below, can I have a better performance of load time?

```
<html>
 <body>
   //Something to show to users before page fully loaded
   <div>...</div> 
<?php 
  // loadiing the stuffs 
  // Sql connection and etc.. ?>
<div><?php echo $variables; ?></div>    
<script>
   $('.values').html('<?php echo $values; ?>');
</script>
```

That is, I have the html first, and load the content to the page later (or  through JS), would it decrease the time where users see only a blank page?
Thanks for your input!

Comment: They are different things. php script is processed on the server side before the html page is been return to the client. Therefore your position of html has no effect on the loading speed of the page.

Comment: There are many other factors that can affect your page loading speed. Hardware, Network uplink speed, Database SQL query performance

Comment: I advise you to use some page speed testers like https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ to figure out how to improve your website. Diagnosing the problem is the first step, then google your heart out or come back here to figure out how to implement what needs to be implemented.

Comment: Generally as you have the code written right now (not using php to generate html tags) is faster then generate tags with php. Scripts also may increase the load time if you have many of them, you can try leaving jquery/library scripts in <head> and load rest at the bottom of the site before closing <body>. Check your website with default web developer's tools (ctrl+shift+i in chrome and mozilla). Check as well how long does it take for the server to perform the mysql queries.